# Product function of a list

Tags: python, list, product

```
def product(list):
    n=len(list)
    for i in range(0,n+1):
        product=1
        product=product*list[i]
        return product
```

When given product([1,2,3]), the output is 1 where it has to be 6.

What should I edit in the code to get the correct output?

Comment: Can you share your "list"?

Comment: This code is going to give an `IndexError` on the last iteration.

Comment: Actually it would do if you hadn't put the `return` inside the loop...

Comment: Take your initialisation and return both out of the loop (`product=1` before the loop, `return product` after it), reduce the upper limit of the loop by one (i.e. use `range(0,n)` or just `range(n)`), and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The various bugs in the code:

- Loop is from 0 to n - should be from 0 to n-1
- Initialisation is inside the loop, hence `product` would be overwritten with 1 on every iteration
- `return` is inside the loop, so that it returns on the first iteration.
- It is also not a good idea to use `list` as variable name

With all of these corrected:

```
def product(lst):
    n=len(lst)
    product=1
    for i in range(0,n):        
        product=product*lst[i]
    return product

print(product([2,3,4]))  # example
```

Comment: But in for loop range the extreme term is not included right...so when we write range(0,n) where here n=3 it is iterated till 2 only....

Comment: @neeharikakatragadda That is correct, but n-1 is the last index of the list (0 to n-1).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a list in the below mentioned way rather than using a traditional approach;

```
def product1(list):
    product = 1
    for i in range(len(list)):
        product = product*list[i]
    return product

print(product([1, 2, 3])
```